# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'user'@'host' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, yii, access-denied, mysql-error-1045, database-installation

I understand this question is asked a lot but since the fix is situational, I'm asking this question.

Error: **mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'username'@'boscustweb0406.eigbox.net' (using password: NO)**

So I have a script that I want to install on my shared server.  The script can create a database on it's own but I'm not allowed to do that on this server, so I have to manually create it.

It highlights this line on the error page:

```
67             $userName = $this->userName;
68             $password = $this->password;
69             $databaseName = $this->databaseName;
70             
71             /*$connection = new CDbConnection($localhost,$userName,$password);
72             $connection->active=true;
73             $sql = "SHOW DATABASES LIKE $databaseName";
74             $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
75             $rowCount=$command->execute();  */
76             
77             //$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
78             
79             $con = mysql_connect($localhost,$userName,$password);
80             if (!$con)
81             {
82                 $this->addError('databaseName','Database already exist');
83             }
84             else 
85             {
86                     if(mysql_select_db($databaseName))
87                     {
88                         $this->addError('databaseName','Database already exist');
89                         return false;
90                     }
91             }
```

I've checked and double-checked all details and they are correct.

Here's my validation model:

```
50             $userPassword = base64_encode($_POST['InstallForm']['userPassword']);
51             $name = $_POST['InstallForm']['name'];
52             $compnyName = $_POST['InstallForm']['compnyName'];
53             $language = $_POST['InstallForm']['language'];
54             $timeZone = $_POST['InstallForm']['timeZone'];
55             if($model->validate())
56             {
57                 $con = mysql_connect($hostName,$userName,$password);
58                 $dat = "CREATE database $databaseName";
59                 
60                 $controlVal = '$controllername';
```

You can replicate the issue here: http://staging-sendy.elionweb.com/

Use the host **elionweb.ipagemysql.com**, then put anything else you want in the other fields and you'll get the same error.

I successfully got the script installed on my local machine without any errors, so hopefully someone here can help me figure this out.

Comment: Do not use [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) - these methods are hopelessly outdated and deprecated. Instead look at [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). And since you've tagged your question with `yii` you shouldn't mess around with custom connection code anyway. Instead you can configure Yii's `db` component and be happy.

Comment: Yii has a DB abstraction that comes with it. Use that, instead of the outdated `mysql_*` functions. Also base64 is NOT an appropriate way to store passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "using password: NO" line tells me that your $password variable is empty.

Then I looked into your code, and it seems that the attribute names on the form and your validation model is mismatched. On your form (using the link you provided), I see: name="InstallForm[password]", but in your validation model this code looks like: $userPassword = base64_encode($_POST['InstallForm']['userPassword']); Look a little closer and you'll see that "password" doesn't match "userPassword".

There are a few other mismatched attributes as well. Your form has: name="InstallForm[userName]". But your validation model has: $name = $_POST['InstallForm']['name'];

In addition, the attribute "compnyName" seems to be misspelled, but it seems that you misspelled it through out the code, so that one might not cause any problem.

Comment: userPassword and password are 2 different things.  One is for the admin use and one is for the database.  Same goes for userName and name.  As mentioned in the post, I was able to get the script to install on my local just fine.